# how to do antlr rewriteTokenstream in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use antlr to generate javascript code. and use it to change the tokens (nodes) in my grammer.

I am able to visit the nodes , enter the node and print the value, or exit the node and print the node value.
I want to replace a token of a node if it is a expression.

like if expression is a+1 , I want to replace the expression to replacedString+1

```
/**
 * @author:saurabh
 * sample programme to run the parser for a sample string using antlr
 */

/**
 * dependency injection
 */
var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');
var helloListener = require('./helloListener').helloListener;
var helloLexer = require('./helloLexer');
var helloParser = require('./helloParser');
var helloVisitor = require('./helloVisitor').helloVisitor;

var toRun = function (ruleForEnterAndExitOverride,ruleForgeneratiingTree, inputExpressionString, changeTokenString) {
    var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(inputExpressionString);
    var lexer = new helloLexer.helloLexer(chars);
    var tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    var parser = new helloParser.helloParser(tokens);
    console.log(tokens)
    //var visitor = new helloVisitor.helloVisitor();
    parser.buildParseTrees = true;
    var tree = parser.expression();
    var keyPrinter = function () {
        helloListener.call(this);
        return this;
    };
    keyPrinter.prototype = Object.create(helloListener.prototype);
    keyPrinter.prototype.constructor = keyPrinter;
    //visitor
    var keyVisitor = function(){
        helloVisitor.call(this);
        return this;
    }
    keyVisitor.prototype = Object.create(helloVisitor.prototype);
    keyVisitor.prototype.constructor = keyVisitor;


    //var tree1 = parser.prog();

    //override funciton
    keyPrinter.prototype["enter" + ruleForEnterAndExitOverride] = function (ctx) {
        //var newVal = ctx.getText().replace(ctx.getText(),changeTokenString);
        console.log("enter"+ctx.getText());
        console.log("enter",ctx.start,ctx.end)
        //console.log(ctx.quotedIdentifier())
        return "hi";
    }
    keyPrinter.prototype["exit"+ ruleForEnterAndExitOverride] = function (ctx) {
        //var newVal = ctx.getText().replace(ctx.getText(),changeTokenString);
        console.log("exit"+ctx.getText());
    }
    keyVisitor.prototype["visit"+ruleForEnterAndExitOverride] = function(ctx){
        console.log("visit"+ctx.getText())
        //var newString = ctx.getText().replace(ctx.getText(),changeTokenString);
        //return newString;
        //console.log(ctx)
    }
    var visitor = new keyVisitor();
    var test = visitor["visit"+ruleForEnterAndExitOverride](tree);
    var printer = new keyPrinter();
     antlr4.tree.ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(printer, tree);
    //console.log("out",test)

}
/**
 * @param: ruleFor appending to the listner funciton (starts with capital character of rule name)
 * @param: rule name to generate tree. without any change
 * @param: expression to test
 * @param: new value to be replaced from the @param3 expression
 */
toRun("QuotedIdentifier","quotedIdentifier", "`a`+1", "p");
```

in java doc of antlr its mentioned to use rewritabletokenstreem but I am not able to find a way to do the same in javascript.

Please help

Comment: Probably providing your "Hello" grammar would make your examlpe more complete and thus more easily reproducible